# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php

Am running PHP Version 5.2.17 i got this error on below code

```
        // member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => '',
        ]);
```

Am stuck don't know what wrong with my code, any help is appreciated

Comment: That syntax is invalid for PHP 5.2.

Comment: Thanks, but am little new to PHP stuff, how do i replace that code to higher version?

Comment: Instead of `[` use `array(` and for the closing use `)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Comment: Please upgrade your version of PHP to a modern version... PHP5 is end of life now, and PHP 7.1 is the current latest version

Comment: Thanks, just tried below answers and it work for me like magic

Answer (score 0):

You cant use short array syntax `[]` in PHP < 5.4

So you have to do it the old way `array( )`

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

For your specific case just change it to this

```
    $json = json_encode(array(
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => '',
    ));
```

Comment: @chris85 - TBH I'm not sure how to,  lol

Comment: NM- figured it out...  learn something new every day.

Comment: Under the `tags` you should have a `close` link on the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is not valid anymore. Try this:

```
$arr = array('email_address' => $email, 'status' => '');
$json = json_encode($arr);
```